# scipy.optimize.minimize Newton-CG stops even when second derivative is negative

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

Trying to minimize the sigmoid-curve `f(x)=1/(1+exp(-x))` (which converges to zero at minus infinity and to one at infinity) with

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda x: 1/(1+np.exp(-x)),100,hess=lambda x:-(np.exp(x)*(np.exp(x)-1))/(np.exp(x)+1)**3,jac = lambda x:1/(np.exp(-x/2)+np.exp(x/2))**2,method = 'Newton-CG')
```

I get the following output:

```
     fun: array([ 1.])
     jac: array([  3.72007598e-44])
 message: 'Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
    nfev: 19
    nhev: 1
     nit: 0
    njev: 7
  status: 2
 success: False
       x: array([ 100.])
```

This means, the algorihtm simply stops where it is and claims the minimum is `f(100)=1`, when it really is `f(-infinity)=0`. This answer would be reasonable looking at just the tiny derivative at `x=100` (and considering that the minimum can only be found up to a certain error tolerance), but the negative second derivative (hessian) implies that `x=100` is not even near a local minimum.

How can I avoid the warning message, and how can I force the algorithm to continue until it finds at least a point where `hess(x)>0`? Note that neither the Jacobian nor the Hessian actually run into numerical stability issues; indeed `jac(100)>0` and `hess(100)<0`, from which the minimizer should be able to conclude that the optimum hasn't been reached yet.

PS: This is of course only a toy problem, but I believe it captures the essentials why my real application fails. Also, I'm not set on using Newton-CG, but any method that does not use the second derivative cannot be expected to continue when the jacobian is as small as in the above example, so I do want to use a method that exploits second derivative information

I am using Python3.6.3 and scipy0.19.1

Comment: The hessian at x=100 is -3.7e-44. Although this is negative, it is so small it cannot be practically distinguished from 0. In other words, the curve is too flat in that region to be meaningful for the optimizer. I tend to use [`differential_evolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) in such cases. If you want to make sure you have a reasonable minimum you can further pass the result as starting point to a gradient based optimization routine.

Comment: *"... and claims the minimum is f(100)=1 ..."*  It does not claim this.  Look at the output!  It says right there: 'Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.', and `success: False`.  That means it stopped without finding a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm does not claim the minimum is at 100, it explicitly says that the minimum was not found (success: False), and indicates why: loss of precision. Observe that `1 + np.exp(-100)`, and even `1 + np.exp(-50)`, is exactly 1.0 when the computation is performed in double precision. You gave the optimizer a function that is identically equal to 1 as far as it can tell, it's no wonder that it has nowhere to go looking for smaller values.

The solution is to review the situation in your real problem. It seems the terms are badly scaled if you are optimizing the sum of two things of such vastly different magnitudes. Numerical optimization methods have limited capability of dealing with such issues; human intervention is required to make the problem tractable for them.

Comment: Sorry I misrepresented the algorithm. Despite my bad wording, I was aware of that warning message, but my problem remains that I want to avoid it. I do not believe there is much I can do in my problem to fix the scales, and the resulting constantness of the function. I did check that simply following the gradient until the Hessian becomes positive definite does lead to the optimum, hence my question of I can somehow tell the algorithm to do that

Comment: You can't tell the algorithm to ignore the function that it is supposed to minimize, and just go by the gradient. As a possible workaround, try to modify the function by adding a small multiple of `|x|**2`  (some of variable squared) to it, just enough to get it unstuck from the initial position. With any luck, it will converge to somewhere not far from the minimum, and you can continue from there using the actual function.